# Pushing bytes to EVM stack

Tags: evm, bytes, opcode, bytecode

I am sorry if this question seems to be somewhat bad, but I am trying to work out the stack representation of the following opcodes:

```
PUSH1 60
PUSH2 40
```

would the stack representation of this be:

```
[4040]
[60]
```

so that 2 bytes of 40 are pushed into one index of the stack, or are 2 bytes of 40 indiviudally pushed into the satack, as in:

```
[40]
[40]
[60]
```

again sorry if the question is vague. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's neither of those. `PUSH2` takes the next 2 bytes and pushes it as one word, so this:

```
PUSH1 60
PUSH2 4070
```

Would create this stack:

```
[4070]
[60]
```